# VS2015 View Call Hierarchy stuck Searching

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to find the hierarchy of calls to a method.  I'm using VS2015 Enterprise.
I can find the method that calls my main method but if I drill down to a third level I just get "Searching..." which never goes away.

So I just have two levels in my hierarchy.  Anyone know how to sort this out ?

regards

Erick

Comment: I've the same issue with VS2015 Profession edition. Exact problem with the third level Hierarchy of method calls.

Comment: I actually have this problem with VS2017 (not sure about 2015)

Comment: Vote for fixing this bug: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/65680/call-hierarchy-stuck-searching.html